# What happens if a computer has a packet destined for a destination address that it cannot recognize?

Tags: networking, routing, packet, routing-table

What happens if a computer has a packet destined for a destination address that it cannot recognize?

2. What will the computer do with that packet?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Ethernet frame with an unknown destination MAC address:

- If the input interface belongs to a software bridge, the packet may be forwarded to the apropriate output port in the same bridge.
- Otherwise the packet will be ignored.

If it has a known (local) destination MAC, but carries an IP packet with an unknown IP address:

- If the system has *IP forwarding* (routing) enabled, the packet may be forwarded to another interface according to the system's routing table (and of course firewall policy).
- If the system has IP forwarding disabled, the packet will usually be ignored.

Comment: I think this answer assumed the computer *received* the packet off the network, but I'm not sure OP meant that. OP may have meant that the packet was locally generated.

Answer (score 0):

If a computer is trying to send a packet to a destination IP address that it doesn't own, and that is not within any local subnets or any other subnets for which the computer knows a specific route, it will forward the packet to its default gateway and let that gateway (router) figure out how to route it.